# PHP | How to sort values in array with unique flag?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, magento2

I have an array as collection and ordered it in ascending order with respect to expiry date as below:

```
$creditDetails = $this->_creditFactory->create()
                      ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', 1)
                      ->setOrder('date_expires', 'asc');
```

I have some records which do not have any expiry date i.e NULL

I want such records to come in collection at the end of or after the records which have some expiry date. Now, records without expiry date are executing first.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure about magento. However, in MySQL null values are ranked lower than actual values, so naturally they would appear at the top of an ascending list. However there is a way around this in MySQL.

using a minus sign before the column name, instructs MySQL to push NULL values to a higher ranking (above the thing with the minus sign).

Note: the minus sign operator works really well for integers and dates, but there are other methods you can use for alphanumeric columns.

that said you could try the following.

`$creditDetails = $this->_creditFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', 1)->setOrder('-date_expires', 'asc');`

notice the - before 'date_expires'